# React Router how use props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

i have question)

I have router

```
<Switch>
<Route exact path={`/:lng(en|ru)?`} component={HomeView} />

......

<Route component={NotFoundView} />
</Switch>
```

I need in all component get `{this.props.match.parameters}` and transfer to Another Component for example:

```
return (

    <I18n lang={this.props.match.paraments}>
                .....
    </I18n>

)
```

There are many components i have and each components i must wrap to I18n component. It is not conveniently. Can i wrap one times all components to I18n and in I18n grab `{this.props.match.paraments}`???

Comment: Maybe build your own wrapper around <I18n /> that uses `withRouter`? Let me know if I should elaborate on this idea :)

Comment: In I18n Component already used withRouter but `{this.props.match.paraments}` is empty if  for example location == /en

Comment: Makes no sense to pass language settings to each I18n HOC separately. You should set it up once on the provider layer

Comment: YES. But if i wrap all components one times on top level into I18n i can`t use `{this.props.match.paraments}` in I18n i should use for example `location.pathname.split('/')[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use HOC to create a function
   Example:

```js
function withI18n(Comp, lang){
      return class I18nWrapper extends React.Component{
       ...
       
        render(){
          return(
            <I18n lang={lang}>
              <Comp {...props}/>
            </I18n>
          );
        }
      }
    }
    
// And in Router, you can use withI18n Hoc with render propery of Route component

<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`/:lng(en|ru)?`}
    render={(location, match, history) => {
     return withI18n(HomeView, match.path)
    }}

    ......

    <Route component={NotFoundView} />
    </Switch>
```

2. If I18n component is provider, you should use it to wrap in root tree (in app.js of create-react-app boilerplate).
   In each route component as HomeView, implement a function to update location into state management.

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean i18N is Provider? 

`function mapStateToProps (state) {
  return {...state.i18n}
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
 return {
  actions: bindActionCreators({
   ...change
  }, dispatch),
  dispatch
 }
}
class I18n extends React.Component {
 
 constructor(props){
  super(props);
 }

 changeLanguage(lang){
  this.props.actions.change(lang)
 }

 render(){
  return (
   <div>
    {this.props.children}
   </div>
  );
 
 }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(I18n));`

Comment: It is my i18n Component